# Reactjs Quiz App with API : cannot display the questions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a ReactJs quiz app using API.
After the player select a level, I use redux to store this info and go to Questionnaire page. It will fetch the question according to the level.
I used the level in my fetch but it seems like there is some error in my code when I'm trying to show my questions when the component is initialized.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "../App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function Questionnaire(props) {
  console.log("questionnaire", props.saveLevel);
  const [quizList, setQuizList] = useState([]);
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getQuiz = async () => {
      const data = await fetch(`/quiz?level=${props.saveLevel}`;
      const body = await data.json();
      setQuizList(body.quizQuestion);
    };
    getQuiz();
  }, []);
  console.log("quizinfos", quizList);

  const handleClickAnswer = () => {
    setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="MainContainer">
      {console.log("hello")}
      <h4>Welcome to questionnaire</h4>
      <div>
        <h6>{quizList[currentQuestion].questionText}</h6>
        <div>
          {quizList[currentQuestion].answers.map((element) => {
            return (
              <button onClick={() => handleClickAnswer()}>
                {element.answerText}
              </button>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { saveLevel: state.saveLevel };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Questionnaire);
```

My console display:

```
questionnaire 1
Questionnaire.js:26 quizinfos []
Questionnaire.js:33 hello
Questionnaire.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionText')  
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Questionnaire> component:
Questionnaire.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionText')
```

I tried my API call without displaying the questions and it worked fine, it is not an empty array.
Can someone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access quizList before it finishes fetching that's why you are encountering the error.

You can create a loading state and once the data is arrived show it to the user.

Or you can use something like React Query/SWR to handle your fetching, loading, and error states which I recommend.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already sent a comment but it seems it got erased.